# Static const error [Flash]

Tags: flash, static, constants

With reference to a static constant, an error occurs:

```
TypeError: Error #1009:
    at global$init()[StoneBlock.as:3]
    at Block$cinit()
    at global$init()[Block.as:3]
    at Main()[Main.as:10]
```

Sample.

Main class:

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    public function Main()
    {
        trace(Block.STONE.id);
    }
}
```

Block class:

```
public class Block 
{
    public static const BEDROCK:Block = new Block(1);
    public static const STONE:Block = new StoneBlock(2);

    public var id:int;

    public function Block(id:int)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Stone block class:

```
public class StoneBlock extends Block 
{
    public function StoneBlock(id:int) 
    {
        super(id);
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because the bindings of the static constants are created the first time the class is mentioned. Can you try doing:

```
trace(Block.STONE, Block.STONE.id);
```

Or some thing similar. Technically, it should work as it is, but there's probably some race condition involved at what class is constructed first (Block or StoneBlock).

**EDIT**

The more I think about it, the more I get convinced it's the race condition, where the runtime tries to construct StoneBlock class while constructing Block class (i.e. it's not constructed yet), but StoneBlock requires Block to exist at it's construction time. Unfortunately, it looks like you'll have to redo the constants into getters that will return values upon request:

```
public static const STONE:Block = new StoneBlock(2);
>>>>>
private static var _stone:Block;
public static function get STONE():Block
{
    if (!_stone) _stone = new StoneBlock(2);
    return _stone;
}
```

Because in this way you will be able to deffer the instantiation of the dependent class to the time when the class it depends on is fully constructed. Not a very nice solution, but doesn't look like you have much to choose from.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I decided to do differently:
`public static function init():void
{
 ...
 STONE = new StoneBlock(1);
 ...
}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do.

Can't you do this instead?

```
public static const BEDROCK_ID:int = 1;
```

Comment: I want to do how in the game MineCraft:
public static final Block STONE = (new BlockStone(1, 1)).c(1.5F).b(10.0F).a(h).a("stone");

Comment: You shouldn't base your code on the obfuscated and decompiled code. The code you showed in the comment above is meaningless without a context.

Comment: OK, your option is not suitable. I need to store object class, not their ID.

For what it is - it does not matter. I need to know what the cause of the error.